# Javascript memory leak in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, memory-leaks

I developed a website that is using jquery ajax. Every minute an ajax request send to get json data. This json data is then parsed and inserted into the DOM.

In Chrome and Firefox this works just fine, but in Internet Explorer I have a huge memory leak (after an hour or so the IE process takes up to a few hundred MB's).

How do I start debugging this? How can I see which functions/variables use all this memory?

Comment: Please post your code.  IE6/7 are difficult to debug.  IE8 has built in developer tools.

Comment: Is the process lagging too after that long, or just hogging memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved. It was caused by an outdated jquery version.