# Memory leakage with multiple platforms and multiple versions of IE (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer, memory-leaks

I am working on a very large ASP.NET project that includes multiple different languages including C#, jquery, Javascript, Ajax, SQL etc.

The project works with Diallers, so a number is entered and a headset used to communicate with the client on the other side.  We have recently received complaints from one of our clients regarding climbing memory usage and that they can only dial about 25 times before the memory gets so high and the system becomes so slow and unresponsive that they have to log out, close the program and then log in again.  (We have a WebBrowser Class that handles our application).

Trying to find the memory leak, I tested on 2 different machines with radically different specs:

**PC 1:**

CPU: Pentium 4 2 Ghz

RAM: 512 Mb

OS: Windows XP SP3

**PC 2:**

CPU: Intel Core i7 3770

RAM: 8GB

OS: Windows 7 SP 1

Now here is what bugs me and melts my brain.  Our client runs both XP and Windows 7 machines.  On both, the same problem occurs.  So that is Internet Explorer 8 and Internet Explorer 9 respectively.  On our side, when testing it out at the office, it only happens on the XP machine.  The memory climbs until it is above 302 MB/512MB and then it resets and goes down again.  When the machine and application is idle, the memory stays consistent and doesn't climb, however when I use the application, the memory climbs making me think its not browser related.  The Windows 7 machine, I can't get the memory above 100 MB no matter what I do.  When I leave the application idle, the memory stays consistent.  The strange thing is, this is only reported at one of our many clients.  None of our other clients have this issue.  Making me think it might be something in their environment.

Our application makes use of Ajax and a lot of functionality in jquery.  I have started ruling out Internet Explorer, since it happens on 8 and 9 by the clients.  I am now leaning towards jquery/Ajax.

I have spent days on this now, and I just can't figure out how to go about fixing this problem.  It seems like finding a needle in a haystack.  It can literally be anything, I have even read about Anti-virus or other apps causing problems.

I have read the following articles, but there is no clear answer here:

[Possible memory leaks in Internet Explorer 7/Backbone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715666/possible-memory-leaks-in-internet-explorer-7-backbone)

[Internet explorer 8 memory consumption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546289/internet-explorer-8-memory-consumption)

[Javascript memory leak in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888711/javascript-memory-leak-in-internet-explorer)

If I've missed anything, I apologise.  If anyone has any ideas, please share.

Comment: Have you tried remote debugging on the machine on which leak is occurring ?

Comment: Hi @NaveedButt, our client is Miles away in another city.  So, I have not yet been able to see the clients machine itself.  However the machine that leaks, I have tried to first replicate the problem (the way a user would).  Thing is, the application is huge and has been in production since 2005.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I meant, have you tried remote debugging on the machines (XP one) on which you have reproduced the issue

Comment: One more thing. I think you should try that on Chrome or some other browser as well. This way you will be sure, whether this issue is from internet explorer or not.